# Port still in use after killing npm process?

Tags: node.js, npm

I had npm running in the background (`nohup npm start &`) but need to restart today.

So I found the npm process using `ps -ef | grep npm` and then used kill to stop it by process ID.

However, My node.js app is still working (even though the npm process is no longer found) and when I try to run `npm start` it says the port is still taken.

Solutions?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106561/finding-the-pid-of-the-process-using-a-specific-port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process you're looking for is `node`, not `npm`. `npm start` calls the script defined in `package.json`, which is almost always `node something.js`.