# ESLint doesn't restart after killing port in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint, create-react-app

When I start my create-react-app with `npm run start`, I get the expected ESLint errors based on the recommended react and react-hooks plugin rules in eslintrc.json. The terminal displays the expected errors like the one below, and the compile fails:

`Line 8:10:   'turns' is assigned a value but never used       no-unused-vars`

If I then shut down the CRA with `npx kill-port [port-number]` and then restart the CRA, the app compiles successfully with no ESLint error. So it appears killing the port and recompiling disables ESLint. To get ESLint to run again, I have to make a change to package.json, save, and restart the app.

While that's not too big a deal it's 1) inconvenient, because I have to make an actual content change to package.json -- any dummy whitespace I add just to register a write to the file is stripped out again by Prettier on save and 2) it takes time -- not to mention the time it took to track down what was going on here -- and throwing time away is never fun.

So the question is -- is there an easy way to configure ESLint so that it is enabled every time a CRA project compiles rather than only if a project configuration file changes?

Answer (score 0):

A few days have passed and no one has responded to this question, so I'm just going to answer it so no one else has to waste the time I did figuring it out.

I observed that eslint stops watching your create-react-app project if you kill the port it is running on using  `npx kill-port [xxxx]` then restart the project on the same port.

What that means that if you want to abort your CRA and restart it (for instance due to an infinite loop or some other critical compile issue), using `npx kill-port` is not a safe way to do so. The CRA will recompile and restart after using `npx kill-port`, but eslint won't restart. That means that, unawares to you, your CRA will be running without any React linting which can result in errors creeping into your code.

The only way I've found to abort a CRA and restart it with ESLint enabled is to either 1) make a change the package.json and then use `npx kill-port` or 2) terminate the node process.

Related:

[Port still in use after killing npm process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941898/port-still-in-use-after-killing-npm-process)